# wordpress php page content restrictions

Tags: php, wordpress, restrict

i have 2 member ids, 1 and 2, i wish to only allow id 1 to view certain content on a page, the page id is 63, so i have copied and duplicated page.php and renamed it page-63.php 
then, i have wrapped php get_template_part with the code below, but it does not appear to work, have i put anything in the wrong section or have i missed a step? any help would be gratefully received

```
    <?php if(is_user_logged_in() && tdp_hasMembershipLevel(1) : ?>

    <?php get_template_part( 'content', 'page' ); ?>

   <?php else : ?>

    this is displayed to logged out users or logged in users with any membership other than 1

    <?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: The above code does not seem incorrect by itself. There may be a problem in your `is_user_logged_in()` or `tdp_hasMembershipLevel()` functions, though. Also, you said you want to selectively show a **certain part** of a page. Why don't you put just that part inside an `if...else`?

Answer (score 0):

Just copy the complete file page.php and make it page-63.php, without changing anything to the code apply your `if(){}else{}` conditions within the while loop. You will get the desired results. Or you can add the while loop from page.php to your current code. As per me your current code should be in loop mentioned in page.php.

Comment: this is the current code, perhaps in the wrong place? it still doesnt work (sorry for the mess!) <?php if ( have_posts() ) : ?> <?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?> <article <?php post_class();?>> <?php if(is_user_logged_in() && tdp_hasMembershipLevel(1) : ?> <?php get_template_part( 'content', 'page' ); ?> <?php else : ?> this is displayed to logged out users or logged in users with any membership other than 1 <?php endif; ?> </article> <?php endwhile; ?> <?php else : ?> <?php get_template_part( 'no-results', 'index' ); ?> <?php endif; ?>